# Je ne suis pas sûr de l'exacte cause qui a provoqué ce changement

Tags: adjectifs

> Je ne suis pas sûr de l'**exacte** cause qui a provoqué ce changement.
>
> Je ne suis pas sûr de la cause **exacte** qui a provoqué ce changement.

Est-ce que l'une des phrases est plus belle que l'autre ? Les deux sont correctes, non ?

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais sans doute couramment :

> *Je ne suis pas sûr de la cause exacte de ce changement.* [je peux dire « *...de ce qui cause ce changement* » mais je préfère ce qui précède.]
>  *Je ne sais
> pas exactement ce qui a provoqué/ce qui cause ce changement.*

L'[inversion](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4086) l'« exacte cause » en langage courant et non pour donner un rythme etc. me fait plus penser à l'anglais qu'à autre chose. Plus généralement je préfère les dernières formulations. Selon que la beauté soit abordée sous l'angle du vocabulaire, de la prononciation ou du style, on décidera ; à chacun son goût, j'aime souvent ce qui s'énonce bien et se conçoit aisément.